# Update all rows in table - too slow

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to upload all rows in a table using a `csv` file. There are fields like 'ic_dph','psc','name','mesto'... in the `csv` file and I want to add missing records into the database.

```
with open('phs.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        i+=1
        line = line.strip('\n').decode('cp1250')
        splt = line.split(';')

        if len(splt)==6:
            cur.execute(u"""UPDATE companies SET ic_dph=?,mesto=?,ulica_cislo=?,psc=? WHERE nazov=?""",(splt[0],splt[2],splt[4],splt[3],splt[1]))
        if i%50==0: print i
    conn.commit()
```

This code works correctly, but it is very slov (50 records in several seconds).

Do you have any ideas to improve the speed of updating?

EDIT: According to Gordon Linoff's comment, I've load the data into the table and try to update it that way. But SqliteStudio says that there is a mistake somewhere in the SQL command.

```
UPDATE companies SET companies.ic_dph = financna_sprava.ic_dph, companies.mesto = financna_sprava.mesto, companies.ulica_cislo = financna_sprava.ulica_cislo, companies.psc=financna_sprava.psc WHERE companies.nazov = financna_sprava.nazov
```

Comment: Load the data into the database.  Then you can do a single update using subqueries.

Comment: You are trying to update a sqlite database?

Comment: Yes Burhad, it is Sqlite3 db.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, I've load the data into the database. Now, I have to tables, old table (which i want to update) called 'table1' contains these rows: nazov, ic_dph, mesto, psc, ulica_cislo and other rows. And the table I want to use to update table1 is called 'table2' and contains these rows: nazov, ic_dph, mesto, psc, ulica_cislo. If you know which sqlite command would be correct, could you post it as an answer? Thank you

Comment: USe a JOIN if you want to update a table with data from another

Comment: @Mihai I've tried already to JOIN them but with no success. CREATE TABLE main_table AS (SELECT * FROM companies JOIN financna_sprava)

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesnt support UPDATE in a JOIN so do it with subqueries

```
UPDATE companies
SET companies.ic_dph =
  (SELECT financna_sprava.ic_dph
   FROM financna_sprava
   WHERE companies.nazov = financna_sprava.nazov),
    companies.mesto =
  (SELECT financna_sprava.mesto
   FROM financna_sprava
   WHERE companies.nazov = financna_sprava.nazov),
    companies.ulica_cislo =
  (SELECT financna_sprava.ulica_cislo
   FROM financna_sprava
   WHERE companies.nazov = financna_sprava.nazov),
    companies.psc=
  (SELECT financna_sprava.psc
   FROM financna_sprava
   WHERE companies.nazov = financna_sprava.nazov)
```